# Flutter-Nested lists: Scroll the parent list view when ever the child list reaches to the top or bottom of the list

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, nested

There is a ListView.builder(){} widget inside another ListView.builder(){} widget. There is a bounded height defined to the child list widget. The required behaviour is when ever the child list reaches to the last item, the parent list should start scrolling down even though scrolling is being done on the child list widget. Same should happen when it reaches to the top of its list, the parent list should start scrolling upwards.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Nested List Scrolling"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return index == 2
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 150),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: idx == 9 ? 0 :  10),
                          height: 40,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Inner list item no: ${(idx + 1).toString()}",
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  height: 200,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Outer list item no: ${(index + 1).toString()}",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Initially the the child's physics needs to be set as NeverScrollablePhysics() and control the scrolling of it using the ScrollController() or else the rendering conflict will occur. Create two ScrollControllers and add them to parent and child lists.

The onVerticalDragUpdate function of the GestureDetector will do the action of scrolling the child and the parent as well when reaching to the top or bottom of the child's list.

The final code will be,

```js
  final outerScrollController = ScrollController();
  final innerScrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    outerScrollController.dispose();
    innerScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Nested List Scrolling"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: outerScrollController,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return index == 2 ? Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 150),
              child: GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                  if (innerScrollController.offset >= innerScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                    innerScrollController.jumpTo(innerScrollController.offset - (details.delta.dy - (details.delta.dy - 1)));
                    outerScrollController.jumpTo(outerScrollController.offset - details.delta.dy);
                  } else {
                    innerScrollController.jumpTo(innerScrollController.offset - details.delta.dy);
                  }
                  if (innerScrollController.offset <= innerScrollController.position.minScrollExtent) {
                    outerScrollController.jumpTo(outerScrollController.offset - details.delta.dy);
                    innerScrollController.jumpTo(innerScrollController.offset + details.delta.dy);
                  }
                },
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: innerScrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: idx == 9 ? 0 : 10),
                      height: 40,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Inner list item no: ${(idx + 1).toString()}",
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            height: 200,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Outer list item no: ${(index + 1).toString()}",
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: This approach might not be the best one but will surely work.